# Android PPTP VPN client implementation for ICS

Tags: java, android, vpn, pptp

I try to create a VPN client for ICS with `VpnService`, I read articles about `ToyVpn` and I know what I should create own PPTP tunnel but I can't find any information about how I can create a PPTP tunnel with mschapv2 authentication. After some researching I see what many applications use for creating PPTP tunnel C/C++ language. But I need do it on Java.
Have you any information or references how I can do it?

p.s. Please don't suggest about OpenVpn, I know it and I used it before, but now it is not the right case.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In Theory, I would create a project in api 2.3 using hidden libraries or using reflection for pptp vpn client then make this project as library project. Followed by creating a vpnservice based project in ICS and importing the 2.3 client to only use pptp libraries/protocol support.
As we all know reflection is not possible anymore in ICS. It should work in theory lets see if anyone is sucsessful.